# Back strength oscillating

Tags: strength

My squat strength increases or remains the same, never goes down. 
The same with my bench strength.

However my pull up strength tends to oscillate, some months I'm incredibly weak and some months I'm too strong for my frame.

No injuries happening and I train all body parts the same. Actually I do just 5 exercises; squats,bench,calf raises,windshield wipers and weighted pull ups.

Last month I was able to do 3 sets of 10 repetitions with 33 kilograms, but now it went down to 28 kgs , if I try to use 33kg I can't finish all reps.

This is the second time it happens, and it only happened with pull ups.

How do I train so that my strength is always peaked and never oscillates? It is important for my mental state to not go down in strength, even if it might seem normal to others, I don't like putting effort into things just to get weaker.

Sleep and food is not a factor, I have a monotonous life as a single adult male. I always cook the same foods and sleeping became my best skill, I can fall asleep the moment I shut my eyes and rest my head on the pillow and wake up every morning to go to work feeling well rested.

I don't even remember the last day I had a bad night or skipped/cheated a meal.

Comment: How often are these workouts? Do they vary at all? Where are the pull-ups in the workout?

Comment: If you truly mean “peaked” as in [peaking](https://www.jtsstrength.com/peaking-powerlifting/) then you can’t be peaked all the time as you would burnout very quickly. If you truly are pushing yourself to your very limit every workout then this likely precisely because you’re burned out. That being said, if this isn’t your limit there’s a good chance that it’s likely psychological

Answer (score 1):

In general, the number of factors that contribute to strength on a given day is extraordinarily complex and, quite frankly,  poorly understood.

If there was a single answer that took all factors into account and could accurately predict strength levels for every single person wouldn’t life be easy!

Indeed, many people empirically try to create programs that specifically prepare people to be their strongest on a given day, sometimes called [peaking](https://www.jtsstrength.com/peaking-powerlifting/) which attempt to explain the programming using intuitive and empirically derived concepts such as [fitness vs fatigue curves](https://medium.com/@SandCResearch/what-is-the-fitness-fatigue-model-6a6ca3274aab).

In general however, unless you’re going to your absolute limit, the difference between sessions is most likely psychological.  If you feel sore or generally tired, each rep you do will be perceived as being much harder, simply because you feel generally worse, but this does not necessarily mean you’re actually weaker. Under ordinary circumstances, the things you’re capable of on days you feel stronger, you could likely do on days you feel weak *if* you pushed yourself hard enough. Every rep you do may *feel like* it’s so much more difficult on days you don’t feel as strong, but with a gun to your head you would probably end up doing a similar number of reps on both occasions.

If you are going to your absolute limit, then you may be experiencing [burnout](https://www.jtsstrength.com/fatigue-explained/)